# How to show the "Repositories contributed to" on github

Tags: github

One of our team member create a repository and all other team member can push their own work to this repository. It seems that, under the tab "Contributions" there should be two kinds of directory: "Popular repositories" and "Repositories contributed to". I push my work to this repository from the user Interface of Eclipse. But in the home page of my github, directory "Repositories contributed to" was not shown up and all my push history can only be seen in the "Public activity". How can I make "Repositories contributed to" shown up so others can see my contribution to the team work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Goto this url `https://github.com/{username}/` where username is your GitHub Username and "Repositories contributed to" will be on the right of the page.

Comment: The question has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47564252/11120444

Comment: @avimimoun this is not in anyway similar to the answer you linked to.

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat  I know, but that answers the title of the question. Actually I was looking for this answer (the title) and I thought it might be useful for other people

Answer (score 11):

I found the repositories I've pushed code at https://github.com/settings/repositories

Comment: This isn't showing all of the repositories

Answer (score 10):

I found the other answers cover the issue partially.
One shows repositories with write access only and the other requires you to know the repositories.

Here's how to find all your contributions step-by-step

1. Log in to your GitHub account and visit https://github.com/pulls
2. Filter and remove any organizations (like regular work repository/org) with `-user:org-i-do-not-want`. Add as many org as you want to filter out.
3. You can see all the pull requests you have raised

[image: Screenshot showing how to filter pull requests]

Here's the link format:

`https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3A<GitHub Username>`

Answer (score 9):

This is the best workaround I have found so far, not a direct solution but could be used as a workaround:

You can see the contributions you have made to a repo with:
`https://github.com/{REPO_OWNER}/{REPO_NAME}/commits?author={USER_ID}`

So in your profile, you could put hyperlinks to the repos with that. E.g.,:

```
Contributed to [Caffe][1] and [OpenCV][2]

  [1]: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/commits?author=gineshidalgo99
  [2]: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commits?author=gineshidalgo99
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

By default, GitHub homepage shows public repositories owned by you. You can add any repositories you contributed to by pinning them yourself. After logging in, you can use *Customize your pins* option on the homepage to select the repositories you want to be displayed there. Below is the GitHub guide.

https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile

Hope it helps!